# Is there a way to speed up a function's completion in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to Javascript as I began self-learning just yesterday. I am trying to emulate a type racer game.

(spacebar)  as the input will signify the completion of my attempt to type the current word, and I have functions to check if it is correct/incorrect, and then resets the input.

So if I type `apple` and then   (space), the input field becomes reset.

However the problem is if the user types too quickly, then the first or more character of the next word is included in the input before the reset function.

Example:

words to type: `apple lemon`

user input: `apple lemon`

input field: `apple le` -> upon space, reset() is called and clears input but user already typed `le` once reset() is completed -> `mon`

So I am wondering if there is a way to speed up reset() such that it is called and completed before the next input from the user.

I initially had everything under 1 function "inputMatch", that was called upon keyup, but tried to separate the reset() and inputMatch() functions by having one being called upon keydown, and the other upon keyup.

This is the code I have. I can provide more context/the full code if needed, but since I am new here, I am unsure whether people prefer to read simplified pseudo code or actual code.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputfield" value="" dir="ltr" placeholder="" onkeyup="reset()" onkeydown="inputMatch(event)">
<script>
    const inputMatch = () => {
        var current = word that I am currently attempting to type;
        if(event.keyCode == 32){ //spacebar
            change word that was typed to be either correct or incorrect
        };
        //once at end need to remove the first (current.wordnr - 1) words
    }
    const reset = () => {
        if(event.keyCode == 32){ //spacebar
            document.getElementById('inputfield').value = ""; //clear input field
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show an example on JSBin or CodePen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! My recommendation would be to use the oninput event handler instead of onkeyup/onkeydown. See the following code:

```js
const handle = (input) => {
  if (input.charAt(input.length - 1) === ' ') // If the last character is a space
    reset()
  else // otherwise, handle your input (in your case, use it in your type racing game)
    console.log("Partial word: " + input)
}

const inputField = document.getElementById("inputfield")

const reset = () => {
    console.log("Entered word: " + inputField.value.trimRight())
    inputField.value = ""
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputfield" value="" dir="ltr" placeholder="" oninput="handle(this.value)">
```

oninput runs synchronously, meaning that it's impossible for the user to type too quickly. It also makes the code a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick question, why do you declare inputField as `const` when you intend to alter the value/set it to "" in the reset() function?

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of taste whether you set variables whose CONTENTS you modify as const. For example, I'm happy doing  const arr = []; arr.push(2); because the variable I'm pointing to with arr won't change. const in JS is not like C/C++ const which propagates the guarantee to the whole object.